# How much faster would a semantic segmentation model be with just 2 classes compared to 100 classes?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, efficiency

Let's say I have a semantic segmentation model that distinguishes between 100 classes of objects, and the speed of running the model is 1 image per second.

Now let's say I take the same model architecture (with untrained parameters), and train it to distinguish between just 2  classes of objects.
**Is there any theoretical increase in speed performance under this new model that only detects 2 classes of objects?**  Would the speed, for example, now be 2 or 10 or 20, etc... images per second?

I'm trying to increase the speed of my semantic segmentation model and want to know if it would help at all to decrease the number of model outputs to only those classes I need.  I'm assuming the accuracy would at least increase, but I'd like to know about the benefit to speed, if any.

Comment: Why don't you just try it ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the number of classes doesn't directly impact the speed.  The speed is determined by the size of the neural network.

There is a chance that if you have only 2 classes, then maybe the task becomes easier and you can use a smaller neural network, leading to better speed.

That doesn't seem like the most promising approach to me, though.  Instead, I would first try looking at neural net architectures that are optimized for efficiency (e.g., on mobile devices), e.g., MobileNet, EfficientNet, etc.